# How to send request.user properly to a model form?

Tags: python, django, modelform

I would like to update the configuration of a device using a Model Form. I suceeded in passing the user to the model form and I can choose device_id which belongs to the current user. But when I submit the Form, i get an error: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'user'
Is there also a way to put the additional Field "your_device" as the first (before all other fields) of the model form?

I tried to remove user = request.user from the POST Method in views.py but then I get another error:
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

This is my forms.py:

```
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):

    your_device = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Device.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = [
                    'location',
                    'meas_pos',
                    'loudest_pos',
                    'spl_range',
                    'weighting',
                    'tx_int',
                    'offset',
                    'limit',
                    'notification']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_device'].queryset = Device.objects.filter(Q(customer=user) | Q(admin=user))
```

and my views.py:

```
def config_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfigForm(request.POST, user = request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            object_id = form.cleaned_data.get('your_device')
            id_ = Index.object.get(id=object_id).device_id
            instance.device_id = id_
            index_id=Index.objects.get(device_id=id_)
            instance.cfg_nbr=index_id.current_cfg+1
            index_id.current_cfg=index_id.current_cfg+1
            index_id.cfg_received=False
            index_id.save()
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Configuration successfully changed!')
    else:
        form = ConfigForm(user=request.user)


    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'my_spl/config.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've redefined the signature of the form init, so that the first positional parameter is `user`. So when you pass `request.POST, user=request.user` the first argument is taken to be user, and then the second one... is also user, which can't happen.

The solution is not to change the signature, but to get the user from kwargs:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(ConfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas about the order of the fields? how can I make the additional field 'your_device' be displayed as first before the other fields of the ModelForm?